# «Д'Артаньян и три мушкетера» название фильма. Как писать артикль д'?

Tags: прописная

«Д'Артаньян и три мушкетера» название фильма. Как писать артикль д'? Артикли пишутся со строчной, но в названии вроде как начало предложения, стоит ли писать с прописной?

Comment: Всё правильно сказал Бегемотус. Вот пример из гугл книг (английский, правда, но всё же): *D'Artagnan, faithful to his plan, went the very next morning to pay a visit to M. deBaisemeaux.*

Comment: Хороший же был план у д'Артаньяна, что он с него поутру к Безмо поперся.))),

Comment: @behemothus :))) Эх, вроде в детстве читал "Трёх мушкетёров", но почти ничего не осталось в голове. :( Нашёл, что Безмо комендант Бастилии, а так даже имени не помнил.

Comment: Это "Виконт де Бражелон", судя по всему.

Comment: А его и "Двадцать лет спустя" то ли вообще не читал, то ли начал и бросил, не помню...

Answer (score 1):

С заглавной. В русском языке это закон непреложный. В начале фразы - и вообще там, где это предписано правилами - всегда заглавная.

Кстати говоря, тут проблемы вообще нет. По-французски правило аналогичное. В начале фразы и названий артикли и предлоги пишутся с заглавной - в нашем случае "d'" не артикль, это скорее стянутый предлог. Так что тут особых проблем нет.

Да и в большинстве языков, где используются вообще используются заглавные, оно так же. В качестве курьеза, где это правило может нарушаться, могу только вспомнить голландский (нидерландской версии), где, как говорится, "могут быть варианты". Но это совсем другой разговор.

Comment: Не уверен, что "капитализацию" все поймут в вашем смысле...

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой ОК, хотя я не настолько плохого мнения о читающих.

Comment: Ну что ж, поддержу ваш оптимизм.) Вообще, интересный вопрос, насколько хорошо изобретать новые слова, если смысл очевиден. Наверно, это тоже вопрос эстетики, то есть иногда (и в этом случае) почему бы и нет.

Comment: Так слово-то не я изобрел.  ))) тут можно придраться разве к значению.

Comment: Само слово не вы, но в русском я что-то не нашёл его в этом смысле в словаре.))

Comment: Это да. Словари надо бы специальные смотреть.... В издательских системах точно есть. Лень искать... Ну вот первое попавшееся. https://riptutorial.com/ru/ios/example/5273/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: Действительно, спасибо!)